# tiptap: CharacterCount doesn't count ordered and number list characters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tiptap

`editor.storage.characterCount.characters({mode: 'nodeSize'})` will also count the html tags which messed up the Count Chars

https://codesandbox.io/s/tiptap-vue-58mfot

Type and play with the bulletList and orderedList button. watch the Count Chars text.

any workaround around this?

Comment: What number would you expect for editor content  equal to `<ul><li>text</li></ul>`?